# Can we deduce that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over F if $F[\alpha,\beta]=F(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

So after reading David Cox. book on Galois Theory, it can be shown that “Given a field F, $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ if and only if $\alpha$ is algebraic over F” (See Prop. 4.1.14).

Later, it was mentioned in Prop. 4.1.15 that “Given a field F, if $\alpha_i$ are all algebraic for $1\leq i\leq n$. Then $F[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,…,\alpha_n]= F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,…,\alpha_n)$.”

What I am curious is if the converse of Prop. 4.1.15 is true. In particular, are we able to deduce that “both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over F if $F[\alpha,\beta]=F(\alpha,\beta)$”?

My suspicion is that it is not true. But can’t quite seem to think of a counter example.

**What I have done so far:**

- Using a similar technique to the proof of Prop. 4.1.14, I am able to show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(\beta)$. Similarly, $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.
- The above suggests that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be related in some way if such a counter example exists. For example, $\pi$ and $1/\pi$. (Sadly, this example doesn’t quite satisfy the condition that $F[\alpha,\beta]=F(\alpha,\beta)$)

Comment: It is true, but it is more difficult. This is essentially the statement of [Zariski's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma).

Comment: @Wojowu This feels correct. So may I check if my usage of Zariski’s lemma is correct (Since this is my first time hearing about it)? In this case, the field $F[\alpha,\beta]=F(\alpha,\beta)$ is finitely generated as an associative algebra over F. So by Zariski’s lemma, $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is a finite field extension of F. In particular, by the tower theorem, $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]= [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)] [F(\alpha):F]<\infty$. Since $[F(\alpha):F]$ is finite, $\alpha$ is algebraic over F.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thanks for solving my question!